# how to allow simple user like author in wp to add custom post type in wp-admin?

Tags: php, wordpress

can anybody help me 
this my question 
how to allow simple user like author in wp to add custom post type in wp-admin?
Thanks

Comment: There are plugins for it.

Comment: Thanks but where this plugins ?

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=plugin+for+custom_post+for+user+roles check them out.

Comment: You mean for a "suscriber" to add (submit as draft) a custom post type ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can pass this "capabilities" parameter while registering your custom post type :

```
...,
'capabilities' => array(
        'publish_posts' => 'read',
        'edit_posts' => 'read',
        'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_posts',
        'delete_posts' => 'delete_posts',
        'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_posts',
        'read_private_posts' => 'read',
        'edit_post' => 'read',
        'delete_post' => 'read',
        'read_post' => 'read',
        ),
...
```

Assuming that a "suscriber" has just the **read** capability, he will then be able to access the CPT menu in the admin, list all the CPTs, ...

But this may not be very safe because the **read** capability has nothing to do with what the suscriber will actually do.

It may be better to create a new capability bunch as it's described in WordPress documentation (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type).

You can find a very helpful post if you want to create more accurate [capabilities on a per post basis](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types).

Comment: No, he's not asking for subscriber's capability to add custom_posts. Just users with 'author' role.